# What is unity_facebook_daemon.py? (ubuntu 13)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

This was running on my machine:

```
hatter      5232  /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unity-scopes/picasa/unity_picasa_daemon.py
hatter      5234  /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unity-scopes/facebook/unity_facebook_daemon.py
hatter      5236  /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unity-scopes/flickr/unity_flickr_daemon.py
```

What is it?

Answer (score 1):

[`unity`](https://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/unity/) is the ubuntu desktop environment. Those are messenger plug-ins that integrate with the unity On Screen Display (OSD, aka a notification bar). Notice that they integrate through the [scopes api](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/scopes/sdk-14.10/index/) into the desktop dash.